How to approach proving a recurring sequence as Cauchy sequence?

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined recursively with $$a_1=1,a_{n+1}=1+ \frac{1}{a_{n}}$$Does it define a Cauchy sequence?

First 4 sequence terms: $$a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=\frac{3}{2}, a_4= \frac{5}{3}$$
All I'm able to figure out is that the sequence $a_{n}$ is of the form $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}}$ where $F_{n}$ is Fibbonaci number which converges to golden ratio, can anyone else help me prove it using induction?
My attempt:
We can see that with $$f_x=2-\frac{1}{(1+x)}$$ $\forall n, \; a_{2n+2}=f(a_{2n}), \; a_{2n+3}=f(a_{2n+1})$
This is my plan to prove:
I need to show that the odd and even subsequence is monotonically increasing and bounded $\implies$ odd even subsequence are converging $\implies$ main sequence is converging $\implies$ sequence is Cauchy sequence
Proof that it is monotonically increasing:
Case $n=1$: $a_1=1<a_{2}=2$
Case $n=k$: Assume $a_{k}<a_{k+1}$
Case $n=k+1$: Using Induction hypothesis $2- \frac{1}{k+2}< 2- \frac{1}{k+3} \implies a_{k+1}<a_{k+2}$ is true
hence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ sequence is monotonically increasing.
Q1: How do i prove it is bounded. Can i prove with induction that  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; a_{n}< 3$?
Q2: The subsequence of the form $f_x=2-\frac{1}{(1+x)}$ the subsequence converges to 2 where as the sequence converges to Golden ratio. Where am i going wrong?
Q3: In my alternate approach I'm not able to conclude the proof by making it consistence with the definition of Cauchy sequence (i.e $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \forall m,n \geq N, \; \forall \epsilon>0, \; |a_{m}-a_{n}| < \epsilon$).
Different approach:
$|a_{n+1}-a_{n}| = \frac{|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n}||a_{n-1}|}$<$\frac{1}{2}$$|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|$
Which implies that the gap between sequences is becoming smaller and smaller as the sequence grows implying its convergent, but I'm facing difficulty writing it formally.

Identical question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161365/prove-that-the-sequence-of-fibonacci-quotients-is-cauchy

@Amogh They are not quite identical: this one with $a_{n+1}=1+ \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ converges to $\phi\approx 1.618$ while the other with $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}$ converges to $\frac1\phi=\phi-1\approx 0.618$.  This one in fact generates the reciprocal of the other one.

I have explained where Im stuck in my solution . This is my plan to prove:
I need to show that the odd and even subsequence is monotonically increasing and bounded hence are converging implying that the main sequence is converging hence Cauchy.

You say "it is of the form $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$".  What does "it" refer to?  Is this a formula for $a_n$?

You state that "the sequence is of the form $f(x)=2-\frac{1}{1+x}$.  $f$ is a function, not a sequence, so what sequence are you referring to?

You state that you're having trouble in the last step of the induction, can you show the work of your induction?

In the final chain of inequalities, have you proved them?  What formal part are you having trouble with?

Your "different approach" seems promising. You are proving that the sequence is contractive. It is then a standalone theorem that contractive sequences are Cauchy.

@MichaelBurr updated my question, Can you check now?

@JMM we have not been introduced with the concept of contractive sequence. We are following Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbot, so I was looking proof that uses the definition of Cauchy sequence or Converging sequence

Hint for different approach.  If you have the inequality you wrote:
Show, using induction, that for all $n$,
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_2-a_1|.
$$
Observe, using the triangle inequality and induction, that
$$
|a_{n+k}-a_n|\leq|a_{n+k}-a_{n+k-1}|+|a_{n+k-1}-a_{n+k-2}|+\dots+|a_{n+1}-a_n|.
$$
Now, combine the two inequalities, and use the properties of geometric series to bound $|a_{n+k}-a_n|$ in terms of $|a_1-a_0|$ and a function of $n$ (independent of $k$).

Wouldn't $n$ start from 1?Why did you start sequence from $a_{0}$

I didn't check where the index starts.  I've adjusted the answer now.  The formula is slightly unpleasant, but not too bad.

thanks..got it now
